# How to detect watermark on images?

Tags: python-2.7, neural-network, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

For now Im using tessaract to detect text on the images, which are able to solve half of them, but im stuck at images like [this](https://temporary.media/u/1508159632-None10E8261A12.jpg). please help.

```
try:
    import Image
except ImportError:
    from PIL import Image
import pytesseract,sys
import re
import cv2 
path='C:\\Users\\Raj\\taskocr\\imgs\\'
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 'C:\\Program Files\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract'

def ocrcheck(filepath):
    #print (pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(filepath),config=' -load_system_dawg 0')).encode(sys.stdout.encoding, errors='replace')
    return re.search('[a-zA-Z]+',(pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(filepath),config=' ')).encode(sys.stdout.encoding, errors='replace'))

print ocrcheck(path+'None10E8261A12.jpg')
```